# Python Pandas - Select column based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas

Example dataframe:

| column_name | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 3 | 1 | 7 |
| b | 3 | 2 | 1 | 10 |
| d | 4 | 5 | 33 | 14 |

I want result to look like:

| value |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 2 |
| 14 |

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' docs has a section for looking up data in this way : [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels):

```py
# Get positions and unique values for `column_name`:
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df.column_name)

#Select the columns via a reindex:
result = df.reindex(cols, axis = 1)

# dump down into numpy to select the values:
result = result.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]

df.assign(result = result)
Out[203]:
  column_name  a  b   c   d  result
0           a  5  3   1   7       5
1           b  3  2   1  10       2
2           d  4  5  33  14      14
```